# Is the usage of "by" in this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar

I am writing a research paper in English. I am not sure whether the following sentence is correct or not:

> This paper presents a clustering framework by iteratively performing two stages.

I feel (though cannot explain why) that the "by" part is awkward. I feel the following is more natural:

> This paper presents a clustering framework performing two stages iteratively.

Can you give me an advice which one is better? Or is the first sentence all right?

Comment: Can you add some background information about the clustering framework to your question? That will help someone write a more useful answer.

Comment: Neither sentence makes any sense. How can a paper perform two stages? Two stages of what? Is "clustering framework" a technical term? If so, from what field of endevour?

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of the sentence is not clear to me. Are YOU iteratively performing two stages? Does the paper perform stages? Does the framework?

Since I don't know how a person or paper would iteratively perform two stages, I am assuming it's the framework that performs them. In that case, you might want to say:

> This paper presents a clustering framework that iteratively performs two stages.

If I have your meaning wrong, please advise and I'll be glad to change my response.

Comment: As far as I know **advice** is the noun. You should have written **advise**.

Comment: Sorry for the typo - you are of course correct. I'll correct my answer.